# convert historic local time to UTC taking into account of daylight saving

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc-time

How should I convert historic local time to UTC taking into account of daylight saving?

The main problem is the daylight saving doesn't occur at a fixed period every year and hence I cannot think of a way to do this task.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate.  Notice [this answer specific to SQL 2016+](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229407/21924)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport by Matt Johnson for Sql Server 2008R2+.

Comment: do we have anything similar to from_tz of oracle in SQL Server or any other builtin function that does the job?

Comment: Really `from_tz` only marks datetime with the timezone. Operator for converting the value is `AT TIME ZONE` . It was introduced in Sql Server 2016.