# Oddities with AT TIME ZONE and UTC offsets

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone, utc-time

I don't understand the difference between these two columns. America/Chicago timezone is UTC-6, so I expect both to return the same result:

```
select timezone('America/Chicago', '2017-01-01 12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
       timezone('UTC-6'          , '2017-01-01 12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
```

However, the result is:

```
2017-01-01 06:00:00 | 2017-01-01 18:00:00
```

Also, this behavior is highly awkward,

```
SELECT '1:00 -1'::time with time zone AT TIME ZONE '-1'; 
  timezone   
-------------
 03:00:00+01
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This is *really* stupid on PostgreSQL's part you can even better parody this with showing the offsets at both sides and not involving the abbreviations: `SELECT '1:00 -1'::time with time zone AT TIME ZONE '-1';`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A time zone ***name*** carries more information than an ***abbreviation*** or a simple time zone ***offset***. *'UTC-6'* is a "POSIX-style time zone specification" which is just an abbreviation plus offset.
[The manual on ***Time Zones***:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - A full time zone name, for example `America/New_York`. [...]
> - A time zone abbreviation, for example `PST`. [...]
> - In addition to the timezone names and abbreviations, PostgreSQL will
>   accept POSIX-style time zone specifications of the form *`STDoffset`* or
>   *`STDoffsetDST`*, where *`STD`* is a zone abbreviation, offset is a numeric
>   *`offset`* in hours west from UTC, and *`DST`* is an optional daylight-savings
>   zone abbreviation, assumed to stand for one hour ahead of the given
>   offset.

The difference you observe stems from another oddity. You have to use **`+`** instead of **`-`**:

```
timezone('UTC+6', '2017-01-01 12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

[The manual again:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names,
> positive offsets are used for locations **west** of Greenwich. Everywhere
> else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive
> timezone offsets are **east** of Greenwich.

However, even after fixing the offset error, both expressions are ***still not equivalent***. Among other things, a time zone name like *'America/Chicago'* also considers rules for daylight saving time (DST).

BTW, your expression can be simplified to:

```
timestamptz '2017-01-01 12:00:00 +0' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+6'
```

But you probably want the time zone *name*, to be safe:

```
timestamptz '2017-01-01 12:00:00 +0' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'
```

Related:

- ["AT TIME ZONE" with zone name PostgreSQL bug?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30787/at-time-zone-with-zone-name-postgresql-bug/31096#31096)
- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

---

To address **your second example**:

> ```
> SELECT '1:00 -1'::time with time zone AT TIME ZONE '-1';
> ```

Simplified, equivalent syntax:

```
SELECT timetz '1:00 -1' AT TIME ZONE '-1';
```

The two instances of the literal `-1` have **different *meaning***. The first offset is part of the `*timetz*` literal signifying a location ***east*** of Greenwich (complying to the SQL standard). The second is a *POSIX-style time zone specifications* signifying an offset ***west*** of Greenwich. In the absence of a zone specification, UTC is assumed as base. See:

- [Why does PostgreSQL interpret numeric UTC offset as POSIX and not ISO-8601?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215905/why-does-postgresql-interpret-numeric-utc-offset-as-posix-and-not-iso-8601/215911#215911)

Also note that the [`AT TIME ZONE` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) returns `timetz` for `timetz` input. It just re-bases the time literal on a different offset. This is different from its use with `timestamp` / `timestamptz` input, where the data type is also switched.

But do not use the data type `timetz` (`time with time zone`) ***at all***. It's broken by design and only included in Postgres because it's part of standard SQL. It's use is explicitly discouraged. See:

- [What is a valid use case for using TIME WITH TIME ZONE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187351/what-is-a-valid-use-case-for-using-time-with-time-zone/187359#187359)

Comment: This is a super helpful answer.

Comment: This is super stupid on PostgreSQL's part. wtf were they thinking. =(

Comment: Also in the event you find yourself asking wtf was POSIX thinking (which I find myself increasingly doing), you can at least read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104088/why-does-tz-utc-8-produce-dates-that-are-utc8 : hint US-centrism.