# SQL query display # of events per day between two time ranges

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, count, date

I have the following table:

```
id      start_date                 end_date                    status
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1a      2020-04-09 21:34:00.000    2020-04-13 15:46:52.000      green
1a      2020-04-13 15:46:52.000    2020-04-16 15:46:52.000      red
1a      2020-04-16 15:46:52.000    null                         yellow
2a      2020-04-09 20:33:00.000    2020-04-16 15:46:52.000      green
2a      2020-04-16 15:46:52.000    2020-04-21 15:46:52.000      red
2a      2020-04-21 15:46:52.000    null                         yellow
3a      2020-04-09 21:34:00.000    2020-04-09 22:34:00.000      green
3a      2020-04-09 22:34:00.000    2020-04-09 23:36:00.000      red
3a      2020-04-09 23:36:00.000    2020-04-09 23:38:00.000      yellow
3a      2020-04-09 23:38:00.000    null                         red
```

I am interested to count how many unique ids were in each state everyday between two time ranges. So I need to generate days between two time ranges as a starter. For example, item with id `1a` was green everyday from `2020-04-09 21:34:00.000` to `2020-04-13 15:46:52.000` and I need to count that.

**Edit:**
The most important thing is that if one item changes several states on the same day, I need to count it only once for the most recent state on a day. For example, item with id `3a` changed states several times on `2020-04-09`. However, I only care about the most recent state which is red (on `2020-04-09 23:38:00.000`). This is to make sure that I don't artificially inflate the data.

My desired output is this:

```
day           state          total       ids
2020-04-09    green          2           [1a, 2a]
2020-04-09.   yellow         0           []
2020-04-09.   red            1           [3a]
2020-04-10.   green          2           [1a, 2a]
2020-04-10.   yellow         0           []
.....etc
```

I have this query:

```
 select serie.day as time,
 a.state,
 count(a.start_date) as total,
 a.id
 from (
 SELECT date_series::date AS day
    FROM generate_series(
        '2020-04-09 00:00:00.000'::date,
        '2020-04-24 15:22:22.000',
        '1 day'
    ) AS date_series
 ) as serie
 left join event_entries a on a.start_date::date = serie.day::date 
 group by serie.day, a.state, a.id order by time
```

But it only records the total # ids per state on the start_date and nothing in between.
How can I refactor this query to produce the desired result?

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=963a55349e767ff4f26ff69957a4bdb4)

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW, I updated my post with the fiddle

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW yes, I updated the table to set the end_date for the last entry of 3a to null, indicating that 3a is currently in a red state as of 2020-04-09 23:38:00.000

Comment: @Akina, I have a fiddle with the scripts to create the table + fill it with the data. I did not include the entire output as it is very long and you get the point when reading the problem.

Comment: Well, show **complete desired output** for your fiddle (and do not forget that the data in the fiddle differs from one in the question text).

Comment: I have edited my post to say that if an item changed to different states on the same day, I am only interested to count it once for the most recent state on that day.

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW yes, that is a correct assumption. in fact, I will update the post & fiddle to reflect that (change the end_date for the last entry to null per id)

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW I don't understand -- Id 1a is green from 2020-04-09 to 2020-04-13, red from 2020-04-13 to 2020-04-16, and yellow from 2020-04-16 to now()

Comment: Sorry - my bad. Looked at times but not different dates - apologies!

Answer (score 1):

The following solution assumes that most IDs (`event_entries.id`) have entries for most days. For different data distributions, different solutions will be (much) faster. You didn't specify.

**Full solution**:

```
SELECT (the_day AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date AS "day"  -- UTC days
     , state
     , COALESCE(e.ct, 0) AS total
     , COALESCE(e.ids, '{}') AS ids
FROM  (
   SELECT d.the_day, a.state, count(*) AS ct, array_agg(i.id) AS ids
   FROM   generate_series(timestamptz '2020-04-09 00:00:00+0'  -- UTC timestamps
                        , timestamptz '2020-04-24 15:22:22+0'
                        , interval    '1 day') d(the_day)
   CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM event_entries) AS i  -- there are faster ways
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT state
      FROM   event_entries a
      WHERE  a.id = i.id
      AND    a.start_date <  d.the_day + interval '1 day'
      AND   (a.end_date   >= d.the_day OR a.end_date IS NULL)
      ORDER  BY a.end_date DESC  -- NULLS FIRST is the default we need
      LIMIT  1
      ) a
   GROUP  BY d.the_day, a.state
   ) e
RIGHT JOIN (
   generate_series(timestamptz '2020-04-09 00:00:00+0'  -- UTC timestamps
                 , timestamptz '2020-04-24 15:22:22+0'
                 , interval    '1 day') d(the_day)
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT state FROM event_entries) s -- there are faster ways
   ) e0  USING (the_day, state)
ORDER  BY the_day, state;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f616c2e448ad930ee04ed8f5f30dbb30)*

The **core solution** is:

```
SELECT (d.the_day AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::date AS "day"  -- UTC days
     , a.state
     , count(*) AS ct
     , array_agg(i.id) AS ids
FROM   generate_series(timestamptz '2020-04-09 00:00:00+0'  -- UTC timestamps
                     , timestamptz '2020-04-24 15:22:22+0'
                     , interval    '1 day') d(the_day)
CROSS  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM event_entries) AS i  -- there are faster ways
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT state
   FROM   event_entries a
   WHERE  a.id = i.id
   AND    a.start_date <  d.the_day + interval '1 day'
   AND   (a.end_date   >= d.the_day OR a.end_date IS NULL)
   ORDER  BY a.end_date DESC  -- NULLS FIRST is the default we need
   LIMIT  1
   ) a
GROUP  BY d.the_day, a.state
ORDER  BY d.the_day, a.state;
```

`RIGHT JOIN` that to a Cartesian product of all states and days to include missing states with a total of 0, and arrive at the full solution above.

#### Explanation

The core solution starts with a Cartesian Product (`CROSS JOIN`) of all days of interest (`d`) and all IDs (`i`). Note the adapted `generate_series()` expression. Since your table holds `timestamptz`, it's simplest and fastest to work with `timestamptz` all the way. This also fixes the widespread, sneaky corner-case error with dates silently depending on the current `TimeZone` setting of the session. I assumed UTC days. Replace with your time zone. See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)
- [Update value in timestamptz column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202677/update-value-in-timestamptz-column/202686#202686)

To work with standard calendar days, the first argument to `generate_series()` should have a `00:00` time component. You can adapt to shift days any way you like.

Since the same derived table generated with `generate_series()` is used twice, we might break that out into a CTE. But `generate_series()` is so fast that the overhead hardly pays.

The `LATERAL` subquery `a` then picks the latest ( = effective) state for each of these combinations. The special case `end_date IS NULL` counts as latest entry. Since `NULL` sorts first in descending order, this falls in line effortlessly. See:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622046/939860)

A multicolumn index on `(id, start_date, end_date DESC)` should help performance *a lot*. See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

Alternatively, consider the SQL `OVERLAPS` operator, or (maybe best) `tstzrange` data types (and matching indexes). See:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)

In the outer `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` & `ORDER BY` to arrive at your counts.

I added the not *"there are faster ways"* two times for subqueries that should really be replaced with tables readily holding unique rows for (much) better performance. You didn't specify what's at our disposal.