# Time zone lost when returning timestamp with time zone from a function

Tags: postgresql, functions, timestamp, timezone

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION laborable_day(dtDateTime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) 
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AS $$
DECLARE
  _isHoliday BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 INTO _isHoliday 
    FROM holidays 
    WHERE holiday = DATE(dtDateTime);
    
    IF _isHoliday THEN
      dtDateTime := dtDateTime + INTERVAL '1 DAY';
    ELSE
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN dtDateTime;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT SECURITY DEFINER;
```

If I run this command:

```
select laborable_day('2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05'::TIMESTAMPTZ);
```

I get:

```
+------------------------------+
| laborable_day                |
|------------------------------|
| 2022-01-02 23:53:11.14297+00 |
+------------------------------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.012s
```

Why is the time zone info lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) **does not store any time zone information**. That's a common misconception, inspired by the misleading name. (Blame the SQL standards committee!) You are not the first to fall for this:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876266/939860)

The time offset is just an input modifier / output decorator. Postgres always stores UTC time internally. Basics here:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Consider this demo:

```
test=> SET timezone = 'UTC';
SET
test=> SELECT timestamptz '2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05';
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 2022-01-01 23:53:11.14297+00
(1 row)

test=> SET timezone = 'America/New_York';
SET

test=> SELECT timestamptz '2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05';
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05

test=> SELECT timestamptz '2022-03-21 18:53:11.14297-05';
         timestamptz          
------------------------------
 2022-03-21 19:53:11.14297-04
(1 row)
```

Note also how DST changes for the last call. See:

- [Oddities with AT TIME ZONE and UTC offsets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160065/oddities-with-at-time-zone-and-utc-offsets/160083#160083)

This also goes to show why your current function is inherently unreliable. A plain cast from `timestamptz` to `date` assumes the current time zone setting of your session. A date is not clearly defined without also giving the timezone it applies to. If you are fine with the fuzzy definition, consider this improved (but still naive) function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION laborable_day(INOUT _dt timestamptz)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS  -- why SECURITY DEFINER ?
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      IF EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM holidays
         WHERE  holiday = _dt::date  -- depends on current time zone! 
         ) THEN
         _dt := _dt + interval '1 day';
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

I removed `SECURITY DEFINER`. Only use this when *necessary*, as it's potentially dangerous. Instead, grant `SELECT` for your `holidays` table to `PUBLIC`.

Using an [`INOUT` parameter for simplicity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169928/939860).

About `EXISTS`:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892796/939860)

I also replaced your mixed-case identifiers. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)

#### Deterministic function

To get deterministic results, also define the time zone. Like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION laborable_day(INOUT _dt timestamptz, _tz text DEFAULT 'UTC')  -- default UTC?
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS  -- why SECURITY DEFINER ?
$func$
DECLARE
   _day date := (_dt AT TIME ZONE _tz)::date;
   _inc int := 0;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      IF EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM holidays
         WHERE  holiday = _day + _inc
         ) THEN
         _inc := _inc + 1;
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  _dt := _dt + interval '1 day' * _inc;
END
$func$;
```

I added 'UTC' as `DEFAULT` for the second parameter. Adapt to your needs. About parameter defaults:

- [Optional argument in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11604187/939860)

You can just [add `integer` to a `date`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742129/939860).

I'd suggest *not* to "overload" the function (create variants with different function parameters), that can get tricky.

This way you can still call the function giving just a `timestamptz`:

```
SELECT laborable_day('2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05');
```

To get results for a given timezone, i.e. 'Europe/Vienna':

```
SELECT laborable_day('2022-01-01 18:53:11.14297-05', 'Europe/Vienna');
```

Use time zone **names**, not abbreviations or numerical offsets, to make it work properly with DST and other oddities.

- [Oddities with AT TIME ZONE and UTC offsets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160065/oddities-with-at-time-zone-and-utc-offsets/160083#160083)

Find available time zone names in [`pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html).

Comment: First off, very thanks for your feedback. I'm using your deterministic function, and I run `select cyp_system.laborable_day('2022-01-02 18:53:11.14297-05', 'America/Lima');` and got `2022-01-02 23:53:11.14297+00`, so I run `select cyp_system.laborable_day('2022-01-02 18:53:11.14297-05', 'America/Lima') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Lima';` and I got `2022-01-02 18:53:11.14297`. This should be simpler, damn SQL standards committee! i will watch them burn in hell.. XD

Comment: Well, I only blame them for the misleading type name. All the rest of the complication has other roots ... ;)