# Limit results of complex query to most frequent values in given attribute

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-performance, group-by, sum

Say that you have the following tables for a multi store platform

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  store_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ordered_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX ON orders (store_id);
```

```
CREATE TABLE order_lines (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  order_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES orders (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  item_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES items (id),
  quantity INT
);

CREATE INDEX ON order_lines (order_id);
CREATE INDEX ON order_lines (item_id);
```

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  store_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  color VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  size VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(255)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE returns (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  order_line_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES order_lines (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  returned_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  quantity INT NOT NULL,
  reason VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE INDEX ON returns (order_line_id);
```

From this I would like to get a list of all orders during a date range and calculate certain metrics, like how many items were bought, how many was returned etc. I would also like to do this for a subset of the items based on color or size, but I also want them to be "ranked". For example, I would like to show these metrics for the items that had a color that was part of the most returned colors, over all.

What I have come up with so far is to do this in two queries. First one is to go through all of the returns and group them by color and sum the items, return, like below:

```
select
  i.color,
  trunc(sum(r.quantity)::numeric / sum(ol.quantity)::numeric, 2) as return_rate 
from orders o
inner join
  order_lines ol on ol.order_id = o.id
inner join
  items i on i.id = ol.item_id
left outer join
  returns r on r.order_line_id = ol.id
group by i.color
order by return_rate desc nulls last 
limit 4;

    color     | return_rate 
--------------+-------------
 Black        |       0.43
 Blue         |       0.41
 White        |       0.40
 Yellow       |       0.39
```

Based on this query I would then do a new one that groups all orders by day(date) and then sums up the total return rate and the return rate for the top returned colors during a time range. I would also like to be able to filter this by for example size, category etc on the items. It will be used for a dynamic report where people can see the total number of orders, returns, rate as well as a line chart of the average return rate, top returned colors over a selected time range.

Is there any better ways of doing this? It feels a bit wrong to traverse and do all of the joins twice. Read some about window functions but wasn't able to figure out if it was applicable here.

Started on a fiddle here with my naive approach as well as one with CTE to try to reuse the bulk data. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/10700

It obviously performs a bit different locally with around 100k rows, here's a explain analyze plan of the CTE query being run locally.

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=50730.74..50809.91 rows=2262 width=68) (actual time=350.787..351.912 rows=722 loops=1)
   Group Key: ((order_return_items.date)::date), order_return_items.color
   CTE order_return_items
     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=33884.69..39240.19 rows=226239 width=33) (actual time=211.390..258.041 rows=194309 loops=1)
           Group Key: o.ordered_at, i.color
           Planned Partitions: 4  Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 9265kB  Disk Usage: 7736kB
           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=5740.52..14725.07 rows=226239 width=25) (actual time=44.080..158.610 rows=226902 loops=1)
                 Hash Cond: (ol.id = r.order_line_id)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=3754.69..9321.56 rows=226239 width=29) (actual time=31.592..107.385 rows=226239 loops=1)
                       Hash Cond: (ol.item_id = i.id)
                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=3572.53..8544.81 rows=226239 width=28) (actual time=29.966..79.287 rows=226239 loops=1)
                             Hash Cond: (ol.order_id = o.id)
                             ->  Seq Scan on order_lines ol  (cost=0.00..4378.39 rows=226239 width=28) (actual time=0.012..10.556 rows=226239 loops=1)
                             ->  Hash  (cost=2363.90..2363.90 rows=96690 width=16) (actual time=29.931..29.931 rows=96690 loops=1)
                                   Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 5557kB
                                   ->  Seq Scan on orders o  (cost=0.00..2363.90 rows=96690 width=16) (actual time=0.005..13.289 rows=96690 loops=1)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=137.63..137.63 rows=3563 width=17) (actual time=1.620..1.621 rows=4462 loops=1)
                             Buckets: 8192 (originally 4096)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 300kB
                             ->  Seq Scan on items i  (cost=0.00..137.63 rows=3563 width=17) (actual time=0.014..0.754 rows=4462 loops=1)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=1248.70..1248.70 rows=58970 width=12) (actual time=12.385..12.385 rows=61098 loops=1)
                       Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3376kB
                       ->  Seq Scan on returns r  (cost=0.00..1248.70 rows=58970 width=12) (actual time=0.007..5.392 rows=61098 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=11490.55..11496.20 rows=2262 width=52) (actual time=350.765..351.008 rows=6567 loops=1)
         Sort Key: ((order_return_items.date)::date), order_return_items.color
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 626kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=6227.62..11364.52 rows=2262 width=52) (actual time=323.014..349.528 rows=6567 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (order_return_items.color = most_returned_colors.color)
               ->  CTE Scan on order_return_items  (cost=0.00..4524.78 rows=226239 width=56) (actual time=211.393..223.913 rows=194309 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=6227.60..6227.60 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=111.569..111.571 rows=2 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                     ->  Subquery Scan on most_returned_colors  (cost=6227.57..6227.60 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=111.564..111.566 rows=2 loops=1)
                           ->  Limit  (cost=6227.57..6227.58 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=111.564..111.565 rows=2 loops=1)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=6227.57..6228.07 rows=200 width=64) (actual time=111.562..111.563 rows=2 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: (trunc((sum(order_return_items_1.r_q) / sum(order_return_items_1.ol_q)), 3)) DESC NULLS LAST
                                       Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=6221.57..6225.57 rows=200 width=64) (actual time=111.538..111.550 rows=44 loops=1)
                                             Group Key: order_return_items_1.color
                                             Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 48kB
                                             ->  CTE Scan on order_return_items order_return_items_1  (cost=0.00..4524.78 rows=226239 width=48) (actual time=0.000..85.098 rows=194309 loops=1)
```

Would also appreciate feedback on the overall structure as well as the indices if any!

Comment: `a similar one that groupes by ordered_at and color` Please be more specific. Ideally provide a fiddle with sample data and the desired result. And always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter, appreciate you taking your time! I updated my question with a fiddle, some better explanation and a query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Query

Your approach with CTEs looks good to me. I have a couple of suggestions:

```
WITH order_return_items AS (
   SELECT (o.ordered_at AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna')::date AS the_day  -- ① deterministic date 
        , i.color
        , sum(r.quantity)::int AS r_q    -- ② cast to int avoid escalation to numeric in next step
        , sum(ol.quantity)::int AS ol_q  -- cannot be 0 (right?!)
   FROM   orders       o
   JOIN   order_lines  ol ON ol.order_id = o.id
   JOIN   items        i  ON i.id = ol.item_id
   LEFT   JOIN returns r  ON r.order_line_id = ol.id
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
, most_returned_colors AS (
   SELECT color  -- don't include total rate while not using it down the line
   FROM   order_return_items
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY sum(r_q) * 10000 / sum(ol_q) DESC NULLS LAST   -- ③
           , color  -- ④ tiebreaker!
   LIMIT  5
   )
SELECT the_day, color
     , COALESCE(round((sum(r_q)::numeric / sum(ol_q)), 3), 0) AS rate  -- ⑤
FROM   most_returned_colors m
JOIN   order_return_items   o USING (color)  -- ⑥
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UMWSjItY)

① A plain cast from `timestamptz` to `date` is flawed as that depends on the `timezone` setting in your session. Can lead to very confusing effects. Define the **time zone** for your dates with an unambiguous **time zone name**. Slightly more expensive, but reliable. See:

- [Oddities with AT TIME ZONE and UTC offsets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160065/oddities-with-at-time-zone-and-utc-offsets/160083#160083)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

② In Postgres, to avoid possible overflow errors, `sum(int)` results in `bigint`, and `sum(bigint)` results in `numeric`. But computations in `numeric` are more expensive. My cast to `integer` is only ok if there can never be an integer overflow (seems safe to assume for orders per day and color). This way, we avoid escalation to `numeric` in the next aggregation step. Minor, optional optimization.

③ My expression should be cheaper and more precise than computation in `numeric` and then `trunc(n, 3)`. The more important question, though: why round or truncate to begin with? At this point it's for ranking, not for display ...

④ I added `color` as tiebreaker. Use anything you deem more appropriate, but make sure that the sort order is deterministic. Else you might get a different result for the same query and same data on your next call. And you'll have a hard time to figure out why.

⑤ For display, `round()` seems to make more sense than `trunc()`. Lesser error. Also, I threw in `COALESCE()` to get a 0 return rate instead of `null` where no returns where registered.

⑥ The join is shorter and cheaper. `IN (SELECT ...)` is potentially different (and more expensive) as it also folds duplicates on the right side. Both are exactly equivalent here, since `m.color` is unique by definition.

#### Indices

While processing all rows, you won't need any indices beyond the PK indices - and probably not even those. Indeed, it's all `Seq Scan` in your query plan. Once you add `WHERE` conditions, matching indices may help (a lot).

#### Overall structure

`returns` is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL. Postgres allows it, but I'd avoid those as identifier. Leads to confusing errors and error messages. I prefer "the_day" over "date" as column name for similar reasons.

`VARCHAR(255)` typically indicates a misunderstanding of Postgres string types. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Question about group by, is there any performance difference with using numbers like you do instead of the column names?

Comment: @nbon: No difference, it's just a syntax shortcut. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850510/939860

Comment: Ok! Semi related question. Say that I have a bunch of different stores and would like to do daily reports based on the query above. Would a materialized view be a good candidate for that? The data is bulk updated once a day so it doesn’t change that often.

Comment: Update only once a day, multiple reports, sounds like a textbook environment for a MV.